# Assignment inside base class list

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaclass

When reading the `typing` module source I noticed following:

```py
class _SpecialForm(_Final, _Immutable, _root=True):
    ...
```

Here, an assignment is inside the base class list.

Later, it's checked in:

```py
class _Final:
    def __init_subclass__(self, *args, **kwds):
        if '_root' not in kwds:
            raise TypeError("Cannot subclass special typing classes")
```

Where exactly does `_root` end up? Docs refer to it as "class keyword arguments" ([https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.**init_subclass**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init_subclass__)), but I couldn't find any further info on this.

Comment: What do you mean where does it end up? Like other methods, if you don't override it it'll end up calling the root implementation, `object.__init_subclass__` (which doesn't accept any keyword arguments). It's not an assignment, it's a keyword argument, as the docs describe it.

Comment: You already found it. It ends up as an argument to `__init_subclass__`. (In this specific case, at least. Generally speaking, it could also go to the metaclass's `__new__`.)

Comment: So its literally only effect is getting passed to `__init_subclass__`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A class keyword argument is any kwyword argument that is passed in the class declaration. Only one such argument have a special treatment - `metaclass=` - this one dictates the callable that will be used to provide the metaclass.

Any other keyword argument there is passed as is to the metaclass `__new__` and `__init__` methods, and to any superclass `__init_subclass__` method. These are not treated in a special way, and, above all, are not "base classes" - the methods mentioned before will receive these keyword arguments normally as any Python method: they may be declared in the method signature, or they may accept the `**kwargs` dictionary (which is the case).

It is worth mentioning that passing such arguments with a proper `__init_subclass__` method in the superclasses that will "swallow" it, the class declaration will fail with a `TypeError` due to the unrecognized argument to `object`'s `__init_subclass__`. In contrast, the default metaclass implementation of `__new__` and `__init__` on the `type` class will simply ignore any extra keywords passed.

Thus:

```
In [1]: class A(test=None): 
   ...:     pass 
   ...:
```

fails with:

```
TypeError: __init_subclass__() takes no keyword arguments
```

While:

```
In [2]: class A: 
   ...:     def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwd): 
   ...:         super().__init_subclass__(cls)
   ...:                                                                                 

In [3]: class B(A, test=None): 
   ...:     pass 
   ...:
```

works with no problems. (`A.__init_subclass__` kwd will be passed `{"test": None}`)